# How to link the Standard IO of native c routines with Androids IO routines ( e.g. edittext )?

Tags: android, android-ndk, stdout, stdin

I am trying to build an app for android, which is using c code through ndk. The c code reads text from the standard input, manipulates it, and puts it to the standard output. This is just like the usual behavior for a console program.

Now I want the user to enter the text in android through edittext. Then this text should be passed to the standard input of the c routine with the help of the ndk.

After the c routine has manipulated the text, the text should go in the opposite direction from the stdout to androids edittext.

I hope that there is a relativ easy way to do this operations that way.

Comment: Stdio os a property of the shell.  And, by default, Android doesn't *have* a (command-line) shell.  Android Linux (Dalvek JVM on top of kernel) != PC Linux (kernel + shell + window manager + ...).  I honestly don't think you can do what you're trying to do, the way you think you can do it.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible.

You can create a C function that accepts a string as a parameter and returns a string, using the parameter and return value to pass the strings back and forth between Java and C. Or, get rid of C entirely and implement all the logic in Java.